# Data value at each marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I show the value of each datapoint at each marker, when plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.plot() ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for plt.annotate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot

Comment: It does the job, but there should be more elegant way.

Comment: @Euphorbium: what does 'more elegant' mean: more visually appealing, or a nicer API call? What's wrong with `plt.annotate()`?

Comment: Well, it takes a loop to annotate all data points, I thought that there should be a function that does just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to add the labels to a given line

```
import matplotlib
def add_labels(line):
    x,y=line.get_data()
    labels=map(','.join,zip(map(lambda s: '%g'%s,x),map(lambda s: '%g'%s,y)))
    map(matplotlib.pyplot.text,x,y,labels)
```

Example usage

```
x=[2,5,7,10]
y=[3.3,5.6,2.1,-.5]
line,= matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x,y)
add_labels(line)
```