# Data value of a variable in each marker within subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, marker, subplot

I'm developing the following function: extract_name_value() that generates a step chart taking the values of a pandas DataFrame in Python, for now it works fine, but I want to add the values of the variable points_axisyvalue or values_list to it in each marker: [Script Here](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/master/Load_File_XML.py)

I tried to use the following examples:[Data value at each marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403153/data-value-at-each-marker), [Matplotlib scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point) or [How to put individual tags for a matplotlib scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-matplotlib-scatter-plot), which would be something like what I want; also I even tried using `plt.annotate()`, but the data of the values does not come out the way I want it, plus I think it would cover up the graph a lot and not appreciate well. Below I put the code in which I'm using plt.annotate():

```
    # Function to extract the Name and Value attributes
    def extract_name_value(signals_df, rootXML):
        # print(signals_df)
        names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
        num_names_list = len(names_list)
        num_axisx = len(signals_df["Name"])
        values_list = [value for pos, value in enumerate(signals_df["Value"])]
        print(values_list)
        points_axisy = signals_df["Value"]
        print(len(points_axisy))

        colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y']
    
        # Creation Graphic
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=num_names_list, figsize=(20, 30), sharex=True)
        plt.suptitle(f'File XML: {rootXML}', fontsize=16,         fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', position=(0.75, 0.95))
        plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, num_axisx), color='SteelBlue', fontweight='bold')
        labels = ['value: {0}'.format(j) for j in values_list]
        print(labels)
        i = 1
        for pos, name in enumerate(names_list):
            # get data
            data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
            print(data)
            # get color
            j = random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
            # get plots by index = pos
            x = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
            y = np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
            ax[pos].plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post', marker='o', color=colors[j], linewidth=3)
            ax[pos].set_ylabel(name, fontsize=8, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=30, labelpad=35)
            ax[pos].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
             ax[pos].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
             ax[pos].grid(alpha=0.4)
             i += 1

             for label, x, y in zip(labels, x, y):
             plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom', bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.5', fc='yellow', alpha=0.5),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))

        plt.show()
```

What I get is the annotations spliced and in different positions.

**But, What does my code need to show each value at each point?**

I've also been trying to use the code from the Matplotlib reference and couldn't get it done: [Marker Reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html). Thank you very much in advance, any comment helps.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you want your plots to look?

Comment: Hello @Yulia, the ideal is the example that I'd in onenotes and I have put here: [example_freehand.png](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/master/example_freehand.png).

I think we would have to use one of the variables marked in yellow or the last one (y) that I show in the following image: [data_values_chart.png](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/master/data_values_chart.png)
But I haven't been able to find how to do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be quite close to what you are after. I randomly generate data, then annotate it using [matplotlib.text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjDUo.png). It's not very pretty, you might want to add some padding and more refinements, but I hope it gives a good idea!

If two points are too close, you might want to annotate one on the left, and the other one on the right, like I am doing for the first point. I have not seen such a situation in the examples that you have given, so it's not handled.

Function `place_label(label, xy, position, ax, pad=0.01)` places the label where you want it to be. The rest of the code is demonstrating that it works, using randomly generated data.

[image]

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that places the label give the desired position
def place_label(label, xy, position, ax, pad=0.01):

  # annotate in the initial position, xy is the top right corner of the bounding box
  t_ = ax.text(x=xy[0], y=xy[1], s=label, fontsize=16)

  # find useful values
  tbb = t_.get_window_extent(renderer=rend)
  abb = ax.get_window_extent(renderer=rend)
  a_xlim, a_ylim = ax.get_xlim(), a_.get_ylim()

  # now adjust the position if needed
  new_xy = [xy[0], xy[1]]

  relative_width = tbb.width/abb.width * (a_xlim[1] - a_xlim[0])
  pad_x = pad * (a_xlim[1] - a_xlim[0])
  assert(position[0] in ['l', 'c', 'r'])
  if position[0] == 'c':
    new_xy[0] -= relative_width/2
  elif position[0] == 'l':
    new_xy[0] -= relative_width + pad_x
  else:
    new_xy[0] += pad_x

  relative_height =  tbb.height/abb.height * (a_ylim[1] - a_ylim[0])
  pad_y = pad * (a_ylim[1] - a_ylim[0])
  assert(position[1] in ['b', 'c', 't'])
  if position[1] == 'c':
    new_xy[1] -= relative_height/2
  elif position[1] == 'b':
    new_xy[1] -= relative_height + pad_y
  else:
    new_xy[1] += pad_y

  t_.set_position(new_xy)

  return t_

# generate data, plot it and annotate it!
axes_qty = 9
axes_gap = 0.035

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = [plt.axes([axes_gap, axes_gap/2 + i*(1/axes_qty), 1-2*axes_gap, 1/axes_qty-axes_gap]) for i in range(axes_qty)]
rend = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

for a_ in ax:
  x_ = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(5)]
  x_ = np.unique(x_)
  y_ = [random.randint(0, 12) for _ in x_]
  # as x is shared, we set the limits in advance, otherwise the adjustments won't be accurate
  a_.set_xlim([-0.5, 10.5])
  
  # plotting the data
  data_ = [[x_[0], y_[0]]]
  for i in range(1, len(x_)):
    data_ += [[x_[i-1], y_[i]], [x_[i], y_[i]]]
  a_.plot([d[0] for d in data_], [d[1] for d in data_])

  mid_y = 0.5 * (a_.get_ylim()[0] + a_.get_ylim()[1])

  # now let's label it
  for i in range(len(x_)):
    # decide what point we annotate
    if i == 0:
      xy = [x_  [0], y_[0]]
    else:
      xy = [x_[i-1], y_[i]]

    # decide its position
    position_0 = 'l' if i == 0 else 'r'
    position_1 = 'b' if xy[1] > mid_y else 't'

    place_label(label=str(xy[1]), xy=xy, position=position_0+position_1, ax=a_)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've been going through your code, integrating the function place_label (label, xy, position, ax, pad = 0.01) with extract_name_value (signals_df, rootXML), but it doesn't come out exactly as I want it [check image](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/develop/example_some_values.png), which is with a value in each marker, there are some values that don't even appear; by the way, the position doesn't matter. To review the code you can see the script directly [here](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/develop/Load_File_XML.py). How could I make each value be in a marker? Thanks.

Comment: one of the reasons is that you are using `get_ylim` before plotting the anything on the axes - this cannot work, obviously.

Comment: Try to replace line 127 in your script with `0.5 * (min(y) + max(y))` and see what happens.

Comment: @MarshRangel the easiest way for you would be to start with my example - it should work, then replace my dummy data with your data - I guess it will still work, then add your axes labels, and other bells and whistles. I honestly think it will be the fastest way to get your task done :)

Comment: also, if, when adding bells and whistles, your code no longer works, you know that it's because of bells and whistles, and you will need to ask a different question on SO.

Comment: I replaced line 127 with this: `0.5 * (min (y) + max (y))` and I get the same

Comment: I will try to replace all my code as you tell me in your fourth comment and I will let you know how it turns out, in the end I can return it as it was, if it does not work; but I hope so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [plt.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) function in a loop to solve your problem.

I randomly generated some data and plotted it as a single plot. You can do the same inside a subplot, the function would be the same.

```
# sample data points for the plot
x=np.arange(1,10)
y=np.linspace(20,40,9)

plt.figure(figsize=[15,5],dpi=200)
plt.plot(x,y,drawstyle='steps-post', marker='o')
# using annotate function to show the changepoints in a loop 
for i in range(len(x)):
    # I rounded the y values as string and used the same x and y coords as the locations
    # next we can give a constant offset points to offset the annotation from each value
    # here I used (-20,20) as the offset values
    plt.annotate(f"{str(round((y[i])))}",(x[i],y[i]),xycoords='data',
                 xytext=(-20,20), textcoords='offset points',color="r",fontsize=12,
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='black'))
```

You can remove the arrowprops if you don't want the arrows.

[image]

## Edited

I used the `example1.xml` file in your GitHub repo and edited the function a bit. All I did was add a loop and an if-else condition to your function.

```
# Initial part is same as yours
names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
num_names_list = len(names_list)
num_axisx = len(signals_df["Name"])
values_list = [value for pos, value in enumerate(signals_df["Value"])]
points_axisy = signals_df["Value"]
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y']
# start new figure
plt.figure(figsize=[20,28],dpi=200)
#start a loop with the subplots
for i in range(len(names_list)):
    # subplot has 14 rows, 1 column and the i+1 represents the i'th plot
    plt.subplot(num_names_list,1,i+1)
    # choose color
    col=np.random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)
    # get the locations of the values with the similar name in your list
    locs=signals_df['Name']==names_list[i]
    # get the values in those locations
    data=signals_df['Value'][locs]
    # arrange the x and y coordinates
    x = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
    y = np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
    # plot the values as usual
    plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post', marker='o', color=colors[col], linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel(names_list[i], fontsize=8, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=30, labelpad=35)
    plt.grid(alpha=0.4)
    # this loop is for annotating the values 
    for j in range(len(x)):
        # I found it is better to alternate the position of the annotations 
        # so that they wont overlap for the adjacent values
        if j%2==0:
            # In this condition the xytext position is (-20,20)
            # this posts the annotation box over the plot value
            plt.annotate(f"Val={round((y[j]))}",(x[j],y[j]),xycoords='data',
                         xytext=(-20,20), textcoords='offset points',color="r",fontsize=8,
                         arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='black'),
                        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', pad=0.5, fc='yellow', alpha=0.5))
        else:
            # In this condition the xytext position is (-20,-20)
            # this posts the annotation box under the plot value
            plt.annotate(f"Val={round((y[j]))}",(x[j],y[j]),xycoords='data',
                 xytext=(-20,-20), textcoords='offset points',color="r",fontsize=8,
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='black'),
                         bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', pad=0.5, fc='yellow', alpha=0.5))
```

### New Function Result

[image]

I hope that it is useful.

Comment: Thanks @ArunRaj131. It is like what I was trying in the last image I share in my question, but what would it be like if I am using subplots, so that it keeps the name, values and the len of the signals? 
See `x = np.hstack ([- 1, data.index.values, len (signals_df) - 1])` 
`y = np.hstack ([0, data.values, data.iloc [-1]])` of the code I share.

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit your code a little bit. See the edited answer and the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @ArunRaj131. One question... The name variable of the plt.ylabel where are you taking it from?

Comment: How did you upload it to tkinter?

Comment: I already fixed it using the same variable from the first for with index inside plt.ylabel, type: `name_list [i]`. I just want to know how you uploaded it to tkinter? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to change the ylabels. I also did it just like you said.

Comment: And, I didn't upload it to tkinter. I don't understand why you got that doubt.

Comment: Oh it's true! you take it out by console. What happens is that in GitHub, I upload it to tkinter: [py script](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/develop/Load_File_XML.py)  but thanks, I'll keep checking it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234878/discussion-between-marsh-rangel-and-arunraj131).