# matplotlib Dashed arrow in 3D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a 3D plot and thinking what is the best way to plot an arrow from one point to another for a given set of co-ordinates.

I found a method in this forum.
I wanted to know if it is possible to have a dashed arrow instead of a solid one in this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/python-matplotlib-plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector)

Comment: strangely adding linestyle="dashed" worked. but what I was trying was linestyle="--" which did not work.

Comment: If you've fixed it then you should move your comment into an answer, and mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that we can add an option as linestyle="dashed" to the same example in Arrow3D as

```
a = Arrow3D([0,1],[0,1],[0,1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k", linestyle="dashed")
```

`linestyle = "--"` does not work because of reason mentioned [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/linestyle-option-for-FancyArrowPatch-and-similar-commands-td39913.html) in the forum.