# How to get Coordinates of a Sphere?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, geometry

I want to know all the coordinates of this plot:

[image]

Source: http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.html

[image]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156353/3755171

And plot it as a sphere of dots(Consider only one of them, I can't find that kind):

[image]

### OR Even the Matrix will Do.

When I tried to plot the above mentioned ones I got:

[image]

### MY CODE

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax = Axes3D(fig)

u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z=np.cos(v)
#ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color="r")

#ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')
ax.plot(x,y,z,"o")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the call to `plot` with `scatter` as shown below then you will re-create a sphere composed entirely of points. See documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax = Axes3D(fig)

u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z=np.cos(v)
#ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color="r")

#ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')
ax.scatter(x,y,z,"o")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Any way I can get the coordinate matrix?? or is it [x[], y[], z[]] ??

Comment: As far as I'm aware the i'th coordinate is (x[i], y[i], z[i]).

Comment: Edit: I'm not sure what I said about the i'th coordinate is indeed correct. If you look at the x array you'll find that each element is multiple values, not a single x coordinate.