# fix graphic isometric figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I Have the following code taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403956/draw-isometric-figure-based-on-matrix/40412894#40412894), in this code a figure of height two is generated by two cubes (upper and bottom), I want generate the figure of height two by a only one figure, likewise the figure of height 3,4,5,...

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cuboid_data(center, N, size=(1,1,1)):
    # code taken from
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715083/python-plotting-a-wireframe-3d-cuboid?noredirect=1&lq=1
    # suppose axis direction: x: to left; y: to inside; z: to upper
    # get the (left, outside, bottom) point
    o = [a - b / 2 for a, b in zip(center, size)]

    l, w, h = size


    x = [[o[0], o[0] + l, o[0] + l, o[0], o[0]],  # x coordinate of points in bottom surface
         [o[0], o[0] + l, o[0] + l, o[0], o[0]],  # x coordinate of points in upper surface
         [o[0], o[0] + l, o[0] + l, o[0], o[0]],  # x coordinate of points in outside surface
         [o[0], o[0] + l, o[0] + l, o[0], o[0]]]  # x coordinate of points in inside surface
    y = [[o[1], o[1], o[1] + w, o[1] + w, o[1]],  # y coordinate of points in bottom surface
         [o[1], o[1], o[1] + w, o[1] + w, o[1]],  # y coordinate of points in upper surface
         [o[1], o[1], o[1], o[1], o[1]],          # y coordinate of points in outside surface
         [o[1] + w, o[1] + w, o[1] + w, o[1] + w, o[1] + w]]    # y coordinate of points in inside surface
    z =      [[0,0,0,0,0],
         [N,N,N,N,N],    
         [0, 0, N,N, 0],
         [0, 0, N, N, 0]]
    return x, y, z

def plotCubeAt(pos=(0,0), N=0, ax=None):
    # Plotting N cube elements at position pos
    if ax !=None:
        if N > 0:
            #for n in range(N):
            X, Y, Z = cuboid_data( (pos[0],pos[1],N),N )
            ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='y', rstride=1, cstride=1)#,linewidth=0)

def plotIsoMatrix(ax, matrix):
    # plot a Matrix 
    # where matrix[i,j] cubes are added at position (i,j) 
    for i  in range(matrix.shape[0]):
            for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
                plotCubeAt(pos=(i,j), N=matrix[i,j], ax=ax)

    l = max(matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1], matrix.max())
    #bb = np.array([(0,0,0), (0,l,0), (l,0,0), (l,l,0),(0,0,l), (0,l,l), (l,0,l), (l,l,l)])
    #ax.plot(bb[:,0], bb[:,1], bb[:,2], "w", alpha=0.0)            



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    #ax.set_aspect('equal')
    matrix = np.array([[2,2],[1,2]])
    plotIsoMatrix(ax, matrix)
    #ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
```

This generate the following figure:

[image]

I want to generate the following figure:

[image]

How fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Before I give a new answer here, could you first accept the answer from [the other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403956/draw-isometric-figure-based-on-matrix/40412894#40412894) as it has apparently been suitable?!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, I'm new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution usiing matplotlib

First of all, if you do not want to have single cubes, but cuboids, there is a much simpler solution - using matplotlib [bar3d](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
matrix = np.array([[2,2],[1,2]])
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(np.arange(matrix.shape[0]),np.arange(matrix.shape[1]) )
xpos = xpos.flatten('F')
ypos = ypos.flatten('F')
zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)
dx = np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = matrix.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='y', zsort='average', linewidth=0)

l = max(matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1], matrix.max())
bb = np.array([(0,0,0), (0,l,0), (l,0,0), (l,l,0),(0,0,l), (0,l,l), (l,0,l), (l,l,l)])
ax.plot(bb[:,0], bb[:,1], bb[:,2], "w", alpha=0.0)
ax.set_axis_off()      
plt.show()
```

[image]

Concerning the overlapping faces of the cuboids, there is no solution in matplotlib. I think this behaviour is commonly considered to be an unresolvable bug, as is also described in the [Matplotlib 3D FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html). Also, manually setting zorder will not work. The good news is, however, that this overlapping is angle dependent. So you will always find a viewing angle (rotate the plot with the mouse) where it looks good.

#### Solution using mayavi

Using Mayavi, one does not have the problem of overlapping faces at all. Also the `barchart` in mayavi is much more convenient, making this only 5 lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1))
matrix = np.array([[2,2],[1,2]])
mlab.barchart(matrix, color=(1.,0.86, 0.12), lateral_scale=1.0)
mlab.show()
```

[image]