# Visualizing a 3d numpy array of 1's and 0's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

Alright so guys I have this 3d array of 1's and 0's which is supposed to represent a 3d object. 0 means that there is nothing there. 1 means that the objects exists in that co-ordinate. I need to display the 3d-object on my screen. It would be ideal for me to have a discrete 3 dimensoinal graph with value depending colors. I tried looking into glumpy and vispy but the documentation page seems to be down right now.

Comment: A good answer will depend on the type of visualization you need (slices, volume, etc.). In any case for high level visualization you can consider: [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/download/), [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). [Vispy](http://vispy.org/) and [Glumpy](https://glumpy.github.io/) probably already have some kind of volume view so I would consider both a possibility. Other than those check if [Galry](https://github.com/rossant/galry/blob/master/docs/gallery.md) also has something like this.

Comment: Just an extra. [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) can also be used to do this. You can use Python, including numpy, inside blender itself. Check [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/is-there-a-tool-for-scientific-visualization-using-blender).

Comment: What do you mean by "value depending colors"? Surely whether or not the point appears in 3D is dependent on the value. Do you mean dependent on the index?

Comment: See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611342/representing-voxels-with-matplotlib)** for the options you have using **matplotlib**.

Comment: The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a [pull request to matplotlib that does exactly this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6404), adding the `ax3d.voxels` function. <s>Unfortunately, it hasn't been reviewed fully yet.</s>

Update: This made it into matplotlib 2.1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# your real data here - some 3d boolean array
x, y, z = np.indices((10, 10, 10))
voxels = (x == y) | (y == z)

ax.voxels(voxels)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Damn, gonna have to wait then?

Comment: You can always include the function there in your own code, using `voxels(ax3d, ...)` instead of `ax3d.voxels`

Comment: Man I am a complete noob with matplotlib. Could you redirect me to a detailed guide?

Comment: A detailed guide to using the function from that pull request? Just copy and paste the function from the diff

Comment: if i dont send an error I get: 

File "3d.py", line 30, in voxels
    color = next(self._get_patches_for_fill.prop_cycler)['color']
AttributeError: type object 'Axes3D' has no attribute '_get_patches_for_fill'

And if i send colors, I get:

self.xy_dataLim.update_from_data_xy(np.array([x, y]).T, not had_data)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xy_dataLim'

Comment: How are you calling `voxels`? Sounds like you're not passing the first argument properly

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G9hHa0yq
Here's my code. I should mention that i copied the voxel function from your pull request and rest of the code from your introduction to the pull request. I had to change the variable voxels to voxelz because python was trying to call the variable instead of the function.

Comment: I don't know why you wrote `voxels(Axes3D,voxelz)` - it should be `voxels(ax, voxelz)`. In python, `some_obj.method(...)` is the same as `SomeClass.method(some_obj, ...)` where `SomeClass == type(some_obj)` (provided there is no `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorator)

Comment: Another option is to simply add `Axes3D.voxels = voxels`, and then the method form will work

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where` to extract the coordinates, and `matplotlib` for the 3D plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.zeros(shape=(20, 20, 20), dtype=np.bool_)
np.fill_diagonal(data, True)

fig = plt.figure()
Axes3D(fig).plot_wireframe(*np.nonzero(data))
plt.show()
```

This plots a basic 3D wireframe according to where the ones appeared in the matrix. You may wish to use `plot_surface` or `scatter` in place of `plot_wireframe`. See [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) for more information.

Comment: I dont have to use numpy.where because my array already only has 1's and 0's. while it looks like its working for the most part, can you recommend me something more faster, this is way too laggy.

Comment: Is `np.where` taking a long time? I would be very surprised if that was the case. Matplotlib, however, is a pile of garbage so I would not be surprised if the rendering of the 3D plot is very slow. You may wish to look into renderring it without popping up the windows and just saving the images as files, but other than that I'm afraid I have no better suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't do the right thing, does it? Doesn't it just plot a line through every point in the mesh in scanline order? Try it with `data[8:12,8:12,8:12] = 1` after the current initialization

Comment: Also, I've edited your answer to use boolean arrays - feel free to revert, but it seemed easier than explaining in the comments

Comment: You're right @Eric, `wireframe` doesn't do the right thing. OP's exact use case is not clear and I felt this was the most likely to be suitable, but of course isn't a perfect solution hence why I listed `scatter` and `plot_surface` as possible alternatives. Seems like the solution from your PR is the best one though. I'll edit this answer once that's merged.

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the x,y,z coordinates of each '1' point to a file and display it with [cloudcompare](http://cloudcompare.org/) or [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net)?

Cloudcompare will even let you store other values after each point and choose how to map these onto colour