# Displaying 3D data with uneven voxel size using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display 3D data using matplolib. I have a list of numpy arrays representing DICOM slices. Each slice contains structure points. I want to display this structure in 3d but dicom voxels are of irregular shape. Ex their shape is [1.4, 1.4, 2]. Is there a way to scale axes in x, y and z dimensions, so it would show how the structure really looks like? Currently, when i display it looks deformed.

Comment: I think you may be interested in parts B. and C. from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42611693/4124317).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass in `x, y, z` into the `voxels` method

```
my_data = ...
x, y, z = np.indices(np.array(my_data.shape) + 1)
x *= 2
y *= 2
z *= 1.4
ax.voxels(x, y, z, my_data)
```

This will produce a plot with correct axis scales, but this may still look deformed unless you set axis scales correctly.