# How to fill a bowl shape with voxels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxel

For instance I have a bathmetry file which represents some points and their elevations - red point below image:

[image]

Can I create a voxels which are filled this figure with segmentation (different colors mean different segmantation in this example there are 3 segments). Box number should be defined by user and a box can not intersects with other segment's box. Box height will be defined by user for each segment.However width and lenght should be rearranged by given bathymetry points.

Comment: General ways to create boxes in 3D are seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611342/representing-voxels-with-matplotlib).

Comment: I saw that question but I can not use that in my problem. Maybe I can not understand that clearly.