# Plot 3D cubes (like voxels) with XYZ labels and different XYZ dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxel

What I want is very similar to the plot in this [thread](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html):

[image]

What I would like to have extra is:

1. x,y,z dimension can be different. For example, x=[0,1,2,3], y=[200,300,400], z=[1000,2000,3000]

(edit:

1. x,y,z can be different in both dimension and units. For example, x=[0,1], y=[200,300,400], z=[1000,2000,3000,4000])
2. If it can allow me to add labels to XYZ axis, that would be perfect. (It is more of a extra requirement as I can manually edit the exported svg)

Effectively, what I want is like this:
[image]

I found something close to what I want in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611342/representing-voxels-with-matplotlib):
[image]

It uses the function `Poly3DCollection`. But I could not figure out how to select the elements such as surface x==0, the line (x==0) and (y==2). Nor do can I figure out how to change the label.

Comment: What are you expecting from `x=[0,1,2,3], y=[200,300,400], z=[1000,2000,3000]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I expect them to replace the axis label in the first figure.

Comment: `ax.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=50)`If you want to put a label on it, you can do this. (X-axis)

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the suggestion. It can indeed solve the label part of the requirement. Now I am just missing making the axises different dimension and different unit.