# Plotting 3D matrix using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D matrix (i.e., grid) `(x,y,z)`, each of which has a value `f`. Let's assume that the grid is bounded, i.e., the matrix forms a cubic lattice.

I want to plot it as a heatmap (or surface), like [this surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJEHs.png). In MATLAB, there is a function called [pcolor3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49985-pcolor3/content/pcolor3/html/pcolor3_documentation.html) which can efficiently do this.

Is there a way of doing this using matplotlib?

EDIT: Or can any python package solve this problem? (still hoping for a matplotlib workaround)

Comment: Such a function does not exist in matplotlib. You may need to find other means for plotting your `f(x,y,z)->scalar` function. Here is a very unconventional example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853556/3d-discrete-heatmap-in-matplotlib