# Matplotlib render all internal voxels (with alpha)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to render a volume in matplotlib. The volume is a simple 7x7x7 cube, and I want to be able to see all internal voxels (even though I know it will look like a mess).

[image]I've been able to render voxels with transparency, but any voxel not on the surface seems to never be drawn.

Each 7x7 slice of the volume should look like this: 
[image]

I've thrown together a MWE

The following code creates a 5x5x5 volume with a red,green,blue,yellow, and cyan 5x5 layers. The alpha of each layer is set to .5, so the whole thing should be see-through.

Then I chang the colors of all non-surface voxels to black with alpha 1, so if they were showing we should be able to see a black box in the center.

Rendering it by itself produces the figure on the left, but if we remove the fill from the cyan layer, we can see that the black box does indeed exist, it is just not being shown because it is 100% occluded even though those occluding voxels have alpha less than 1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # NOQA

spatial_axes = [5, 5, 5]
filled = np.ones(spatial_axes, dtype=np.bool)

colors = np.empty(spatial_axes + [4], dtype=np.float32)
alpha = .5
colors[0] = [1, 0, 0, alpha]
colors[1] = [0, 1, 0, alpha]
colors[2] = [0, 0, 1, alpha]
colors[3] = [1, 1, 0, alpha]
colors[4] = [0, 1, 1, alpha]

# set all internal colors to black with alpha=1
colors[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1, 0:3] = 0
colors[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1, 3] = 1

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot('111', projection='3d')
ax.voxels(filled, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot('111', projection='3d')
filled[-1] = False
ax.voxels(filled, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
```

[image]

Is there any way to render all occluded voxels?

Comment: Did you look at [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html)? It doesn't seem to have this problem, due to some small offsets between the voxels.

Comment: In general, this issue is still being discussed: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9745

Comment: Also, you may always just plot all voxels as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611342/representing-voxels-with-matplotlib) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853556/3d-discrete-heatmap-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Ah, I guess you can see them all in the official example, on first glance it looked like you could not. The other answers also look promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To turn my comments above into an answer:

- You may always just plot all voxels as in

  - [Representing voxels with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611342/representing-voxels-with-matplotlib)
  - [3D discrete heatmap in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853556/3d-discrete-heatmap-in-matplotlib)
- The [official example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html) solves this problem by offsettingt the faces of the voxels by a bit, such they are all drawn.
- [This matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9745) discusses the missing faces on internal cubes. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9927) which has some issues still and it hence not merged yet.

Despite the small issues, you may monkey patch the current status of the pull request into your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, art3d  # NOQA
from matplotlib.cbook import _backports
from collections import defaultdict
import types

def voxels(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if len(args) >= 3:
        # underscores indicate position only
        def voxels(__x, __y, __z, filled, **kwargs):
            return (__x, __y, __z), filled, kwargs
    else:
        def voxels(filled, **kwargs):
            return None, filled, kwargs

    xyz, filled, kwargs = voxels(*args, **kwargs)

    # check dimensions
    if filled.ndim != 3:
        raise ValueError("Argument filled must be 3-dimensional")
    size = np.array(filled.shape, dtype=np.intp)

    # check xyz coordinates, which are one larger than the filled shape
    coord_shape = tuple(size + 1)
    if xyz is None:
        x, y, z = np.indices(coord_shape)
    else:
        x, y, z = (_backports.broadcast_to(c, coord_shape) for c in xyz)

    def _broadcast_color_arg(color, name):
        if np.ndim(color) in (0, 1):
            # single color, like "red" or [1, 0, 0]
            return _backports.broadcast_to(
                color, filled.shape + np.shape(color))
        elif np.ndim(color) in (3, 4):
            # 3D array of strings, or 4D array with last axis rgb
            if np.shape(color)[:3] != filled.shape:
                raise ValueError(
                    "When multidimensional, {} must match the shape of "
                    "filled".format(name))
            return color
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid {} argument".format(name))

    # intercept the facecolors, handling defaults and broacasting
    facecolors = kwargs.pop('facecolors', None)
    if facecolors is None:
        facecolors = self._get_patches_for_fill.get_next_color()
    facecolors = _broadcast_color_arg(facecolors, 'facecolors')

    # broadcast but no default on edgecolors
    edgecolors = kwargs.pop('edgecolors', None)
    edgecolors = _broadcast_color_arg(edgecolors, 'edgecolors')

    # include possibly occluded internal faces or not
    internal_faces = kwargs.pop('internal_faces', False)

    # always scale to the full array, even if the data is only in the center
    self.auto_scale_xyz(x, y, z)

    # points lying on corners of a square
    square = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]
    ], dtype=np.intp)

    voxel_faces = defaultdict(list)

    def permutation_matrices(n):
        """ Generator of cyclic permutation matices """
        mat = np.eye(n, dtype=np.intp)
        for i in range(n):
            yield mat
            mat = np.roll(mat, 1, axis=0)

    for permute in permutation_matrices(3):
        pc, qc, rc = permute.T.dot(size)
        pinds = np.arange(pc)
        qinds = np.arange(qc)
        rinds = np.arange(rc)

        square_rot = square.dot(permute.T)

        for p in pinds:
            for q in qinds:
                p0 = permute.dot([p, q, 0])
                i0 = tuple(p0)
                if filled[i0]:
                    voxel_faces[i0].append(p0 + square_rot)

                # draw middle faces
                for r1, r2 in zip(rinds[:-1], rinds[1:]):
                    p1 = permute.dot([p, q, r1])
                    p2 = permute.dot([p, q, r2])
                    i1 = tuple(p1)
                    i2 = tuple(p2)
                    if filled[i1] and (internal_faces or not filled[i2]):
                        voxel_faces[i1].append(p2 + square_rot)
                    elif (internal_faces or not filled[i1]) and filled[i2]:
                        voxel_faces[i2].append(p2 + square_rot)

                # draw upper faces
                pk = permute.dot([p, q, rc-1])
                pk2 = permute.dot([p, q, rc])
                ik = tuple(pk)
                if filled[ik]:
                    voxel_faces[ik].append(pk2 + square_rot)

    # iterate over the faces, and generate a Poly3DCollection for each voxel
    polygons = {}
    for coord, faces_inds in voxel_faces.items():
        # convert indices into 3D positions
        if xyz is None:
            faces = faces_inds
        else:
            faces = []
            for face_inds in faces_inds:
                ind = face_inds[:, 0], face_inds[:, 1], face_inds[:, 2]
                face = np.empty(face_inds.shape)
                face[:, 0] = x[ind]
                face[:, 1] = y[ind]
                face[:, 2] = z[ind]
                faces.append(face)

        poly = art3d.Poly3DCollection(faces,
            facecolors=facecolors[coord],
            edgecolors=edgecolors[coord],
            **kwargs
        )
        self.add_collection3d(poly)
        polygons[coord] = poly

    return polygons



spatial_axes = [5, 5, 5]
filled = np.ones(spatial_axes, dtype=np.bool)

colors = np.empty(spatial_axes + [4], dtype=np.float32)
alpha = .5
colors[0] = [1, 0, 0, alpha]
colors[1] = [0, 1, 0, alpha]
colors[2] = [0, 0, 1, alpha]
colors[3] = [1, 1, 0, alpha]
colors[4] = [0, 1, 1, alpha]

# set all internal colors to black with alpha=1
colors[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1, 0:3] = 0
colors[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1, 3] = 1

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot('111', projection='3d')
ax.voxels = types.MethodType(voxels, ax)
ax.voxels(filled, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k',internal_faces=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot('111', projection='3d')
ax.voxels = types.MethodType(voxels, ax)
filled[-1] = False
ax.voxels(filled, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k',internal_faces=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: end result image]