# Plot voxel image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3d numpy array (assume it's normalised) which I want to display as a 3d voxel image. I want the voxels to be black and use the stored number in the 3d array as an alpha image so that the pixels with value 1 would be visible and with value 0 would be transparent.

I haven't seen a proper way to display voxels in matplotlib for this particular situation, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib render all internal voxels (with alpha)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672663/matplotlib-render-all-internal-voxels-with-alpha)

Comment: it's not exactly what I was hoping for, but it does make me think that I will be better off with a 3D scatter graph instead