# Plotting 3D cube in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Is there any way to plot a 3D cube from the given following info:
1. bottom left corner coordinate(x,y,z) 
2. dimensions(width, length, and height) of the cube?
Actually I need to plot a bunch of cubes each of those having the above two info. So, if anyone can give me a solution for plotting a single cube, I guess I can plot the rest.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156353/13633195) Does it help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting a 3d cube, a sphere and a vector in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector-in-matplotlib) or [Python Matplotlib - Plotting cuboids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277753/python-matplotlib-plotting-cuboids)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I found this link earlier. In that solution, all sides are of length 2. In my case, it would be a 3D rectangular object. Not necessarily a perfect cube. But I was looking for some other solutions. Like patch object, if there is any way to draw a 3D cube with one vertex and other dimensions?