# 3d curved arrow in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to draw a curved arrow in 3d, please? I mean something similar to the case in 2d:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 3]

plt.xlim(-50,150)
plt.ylim(-60,165)

style="Simple,tail_width=0.5,head_width=4,head_length=8"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style)
a3 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (99, 100),connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3", **kw)

for a in [a3]:
    plt.gca().add_patch(a)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extend [FancyArrowPatch](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html). The idea is to intercept the 3D coordinates parameters. Other parameters are directly passed to the FancyArrowPatch artist.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)

ax1.set_xlim(-50,150)
ax1.set_ylim(-60,165)

style="Simple,tail_width=0.5,head_width=4,head_length=8"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style)
a1 = FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (99, 100),connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3", **kw)

ax1.add_patch(a1)


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):

    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection="3d")

a2 = Arrow3D([0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], mutation_scale=20,
            lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3")

ax2.add_artist(a2)

plt.show()
```

`xs[0], ys[0], zs[0]` is the starting point coordinates, `xs[1], ys[1], zs[1]` is the ending point coordinates.

[image]

Reference:

[Plotting a 3d cube, a sphere and a vector in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156353/10315163)