# matplotlib: get projection coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I saw 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)
 and added a `print label.get_position()`. It looks like this command returns the 2D-coordinates of the label, let's call it (u,v)-coordinates as marked green in the picture below.
Now my question:
Is there a way to get these (u,v)-coordinates of a certain **3D-point**? How?

Edit:
For example:
I have a 3D-point with the (x,y,z)-coordinates (1,1,1). I want matplotlib to return me the (u,v)-coordinates of this point when I rotate the view around. In my example: In the first case, matplotlib should return me (4,3), in the second case (6,4). Hope this is clear enough now =)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  matplotlib only knows about 2D, anything 3D is done via projection to 2D.  As near as I can tell, the question you link to answers any way I can find to interpret  your question.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope you can understand it now :-)

Comment: That is exactly what the code in the question you linked to does.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I think you missunderstand me. If you add these two lines in the code i linked to: `print (x2,y2)
    print label.get_position()` you'll get two completey different values, which behave different when you rotate around. The value I get from `print label.get_position()` is exactly what I want, but that was just an example: I **don't** want to use **labels**, only work with my **points**, so I need a kind of `(1,1,1).get_position()`. Or is there something in the linked code I don't understand?

Comment: I would suggest reading the code in that answer carefully and make sure you understand what every line is doing, not just copy and pasting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: Annotating a 3D scatter plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)  example, you use

```
x2, y2, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(x1,y1,z1, ax.get_proj())
```

To get the projection of 3D -> 2D.

Comment: Oh damn, I always recognized (x2, y2) as (zero, zero) because I compared it with the values from `.get_position()`. But now I see it's the values I wanted. Thank you and I apologize =/

Comment: @Munchkin No worries, glad you see it now.