# how to plot a line over a 3d surface in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3d plot and would like to draw several lines over the surface of the plot. It is not clear to me how I should organize the data of the lines so that it fall on the surface.

Some explanation for the code below: I made a sensitivity analysis on the temperature sensitivity parameters describing the activity of the Rubisco enzym (crucial in photosynthesis). The activation energy, `Ha`, is the only parameter in this equation.

The function `plot_TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics` draws the 3D plot. Now I would like to see the lines for each of the 4 parameters described in the function `TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics` on the surface, with each line nicely labelled.

Some tips on how to structure the data for these lines would be very much appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

cRefTmp_C           = 25.                # [C]
cRefTmp_K           = cRefTmp_C + 273.15 # [K]
MolarGasConstant    = 8.314472           # [J mol-1 K-1]

def TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics(Ha, LeafTemperature_C):
    """
        multiplier for temperature effects on Kc, K0, Ri and GammaStar [ - ]
        formula thesis Manfred Forstreuter p 66 (eq 2.41) 

        Parameter            ParameterValue
        cHaOfGammaStar   29000  
        cHaOfK0      35900
        cHaOfKc      59500
        cHaOfRi      46390   

        refs for equation:
        Harley P.C., Thomas R.B., Reynolds J.F., Strain B.R., 1992. 
            Modelling photosynthesis of cotton grown in elevated CO2. Plant, Cell Environ. 15: 271-282.
        Farquhar G.D., von Caemmerer S. & Berry J.A., 1980. 
            A biochemical model of photosynthetic CO2 assimilation in leaves of C3 species. Planta 149: 78-90.

    """
    LeafTemperature_K = LeafTemperature_C + 273.15               # from Celsius to Kelvin
    return exp(Ha * (LeafTemperature_K - cRefTmp_K) / (MolarGasConstant * LeafTemperature_K * cRefTmp_K))


def plot_TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics():
    Ha     = np.arange(25000., 60000., 1000.)
    T      = np.arange(0., 30., 1)
    Ha,T   = np.meshgrid(Ha,T)
    TEff   = TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics(Ha, T)

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='White')
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    surf = ax.plot_surface(Ha,T,TEff, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
           linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    ax.set_zlim(TEff.min() ,TEff.max())
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

    ax.set_title('Effect of temperature on Michaelis Menten-parameters \n at different Ha values')
    ax.set_xlabel('Activation energy, Ha (J mol-1)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Leaf surface temperature (C)')
    ax.set_zlabel('T-multiplier to reference value')


    plt.show()

plot_TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics()
```

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you can distill this question (and the code!) into the core components. Remove everything that isn't needed!

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally clear from your question which 'lines' you are trying to plot, but my guess is that you want to evaluate `TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics` for some fixed values of `Ha` (`cHaOfGammaStar`, `cHaOfK0` etc.) and the same range of temperature values (0 to 30 in steps of 1).

For example, to plot `cHaOfGammaStar` you could do something like this:

```
cHaOfGammaStar = np.array([29000])
z = TemperatureEffectOnRuBisCOKinetics(cHaOfGammaStar, T)

# we need to hold the axes to plot on top of the surface
ax.hold(True)

# we multiply cHaOfGammaStar by a vector of ones to make it the same length
# as T and z
l, = ax.plot(cHaOfGammaStar * np.ones(T.size), T, z, '--k')

# create a figure legend
ax.figure.legend((l,), ('cHaOfGammaStar',), loc=4, fancybox=True)
```

### Output:

[image]

If you want to do some fancier annotation rather than just using a figure legend, you should take a look at [HYRY's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10394128/1461210).