# Putting arrowheads on vectors in a 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-3d

I plotted the eigenvectors of some 3D-data and was wondering if there is currently (already) a way to put arrowheads on the lines? Would be awesome if someone has a tip for me. [image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

####################################################
# This part is just for reference if
# you are interested where the data is
# coming from
# The plot is at the bottom
#####################################################

# Generate some example data
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class1_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 20)

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,1,1])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class2_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 20)

# concatenate data for PCA
samples = np.concatenate((class1_sample, class2_sample), axis=0)

# mean values
mean_x = mean(samples[:,0])
mean_y = mean(samples[:,1])
mean_z = mean(samples[:,2])

#eigenvectors and eigenvalues
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)

################################
#plotting eigenvectors
################################    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], samples[:,2], 'o', markersize=10, color='green', alpha=0.2)
ax.plot([mean_x], [mean_y], [mean_z], 'o', markersize=10, color='red', alpha=0.5)
for v in eig_vec:
    ax.plot([mean_x, v[0]], [mean_y, v[1]], [mean_z, v[2]], color='red', alpha=0.8, lw=3)
ax.set_xlabel('x_values')
ax.set_ylabel('y_values')
ax.set_zlabel('z_values')

plt.title('Eigenvectors')

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To add arrow patches to a 3D plot, the simple solution is to use `FancyArrowPatch` class defined in `/matplotlib/patches.py`.  However, it only works for 2D plot (at the time of writing), as its `posA` and `posB` are supposed to be tuples of length 2.

Therefore we create a new arrow patch class, name it `Arrow3D`, which inherits from `FancyArrowPatch`.  The only thing we need to override its `posA` and `posB`.  To do that, we initiate `Arrow3d` with `posA` and `posB` of `(0,0)`s.  The 3D coordinates `xs, ys, zs` was then projected from 3D to 2D using `proj3d.proj_transform()`, and the resultant 2D coordinates get assigned to `posA` and `posB` using `.set_position()` method, replacing the `(0,0)`s. This way we get the 3D arrow to work.

The projection steps go into the `.draw` method, which overrides the `.draw` method of the `FancyArrowPatch` object.

This might appear like a hack. However, the `mplot3d` currently only provides (again, only) simple 3D plotting capacity by supplying 3D-2D projections and essentially does all the plotting in 2D, which is not truly 3D.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

####################################################
# This part is just for reference if
# you are interested where the data is
# coming from
# The plot is at the bottom
#####################################################

# Generate some example data
mu_vec1 = np.array([0,0,0])
cov_mat1 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class1_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 20)

mu_vec2 = np.array([1,1,1])
cov_mat2 = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
class2_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 20)
```

Actual drawing. Note that we only need to change one line of your code, which add an new arrow artist:

```
# concatenate data for PCA
samples = np.concatenate((class1_sample, class2_sample), axis=0)

# mean values
mean_x = mean(samples[:,0])
mean_y = mean(samples[:,1])
mean_z = mean(samples[:,2])

#eigenvectors and eigenvalues
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat1)

################################
#plotting eigenvectors
################################    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], samples[:,2], 'o', markersize=10, color='g', alpha=0.2)
ax.plot([mean_x], [mean_y], [mean_z], 'o', markersize=10, color='red', alpha=0.5)
for v in eig_vec:
    #ax.plot([mean_x,v[0]], [mean_y,v[1]], [mean_z,v[2]], color='red', alpha=0.8, lw=3)
    #I will replace this line with:
    a = Arrow3D([mean_x, v[0]], [mean_y, v[1]], 
                [mean_z, v[2]], mutation_scale=20, 
                lw=3, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
    ax.add_artist(a)
ax.set_xlabel('x_values')
ax.set_ylabel('y_values')
ax.set_zlabel('z_values')

plt.title('Eigenvectors')

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: final_output]

Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140163/python-matplotlib-plotting-a-3d-cube-a-sphere-and-a-vector), which inspired this question, for further details.

Comment: This code works in `matplotlib 2.0` without `plt.draw()`. Is that line of code necessary?

Comment: @Seanny123, optional, `.show()` code could also be optional depends on how the environment is setup.  Just for clarity sake I suppose.

Comment: Fantastic answer. It could be improved if there was a way to control the depth-positioning of the arrows drawn. In my case it is undesirable that the arrows are visible over the data point, but I will look into this. EDIT: `arrow.set_zorder(-1)` does the trick, easy as pie.

Comment: Sadly the edit queue is currently full; to add compatibility for matplotlib>=3.5 add a `do_3d_projection = draw` alias into the class definition.

Comment: Oh, and the draw/do_3d_projection function will also need a return value (for z order stacking)

Comment: @mueslo. Followed your advice, still getting some None-to-None comparison errors in 3.5.1.

Comment: @mueslo I try to make this code run in a newer version of matplotlib. So where exactly do I have to add this line of code? Is it a class or instance attribute? And does it refer to self.draw() or to the plt.draw()?

Answer (score 22):

Another option: you can also use the [`plt.quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/quiver3d.html) function, which allows you to produce arrow vectors pretty easily without any extra imports or classes.

To replicate your example, you would replace:

```py
for v in eig_vec:
    ax.plot([mean_x, v[0]], [mean_y, v[1]], [mean_z, v[2]], color='red', alpha=0.8, lw=3)
```

with:

```py
for v in eig_vec:
    ax.quiver(
        mean_x, mean_y, mean_z, # <-- starting point of vector
        v[0] - mean_x, v[1] - mean_y, v[2] - mean_z, # <-- directions of vector
        color = 'red', alpha = .8, lw = 3,
    )
```

Comment: Although using the built-in `quiver` sounds simpler than adding a custom class, it does not support the dtype `float128` as its first six arguments: `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `U`, `V`, and `W`. Because it silently converts the arguments into `float`, they are converted into `float64` in our systems. As a result, if we give it `float128` numbers, they _overflow!_

Comment: Beware, if you are using 3D arrows in matplotlib 3.1.2 or later, you get the [3D matplotlib object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html) object and not the 2D quiver @matt links. cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490404/1391376)

Comment: @ShahrokhBah can you please share your use-case where float32 is inacceptable for plots? Thanks

Comment: Nice, and strange that the 3D option is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver).  Unfortunately, many of the style options, like `scale`, `headwidth` and `headaxislength` don't seem to work in 3D...

Comment: The problem of `quiver` is its arrow size and length scale with the shaft, meaning it is impossible to have a fix sized arrow.

Answer (score 15):

Newer version of matplotlib throwns `AttributeError: 'Arrow3D' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'` with old definition of `Arrow3D`. It was asked here by several comments and still remained kind of unclear. You have to add function `do_3d_projection()`, while `draw()` is no longer needed. Current code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__((0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def do_3d_projection(self, renderer=None):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, self.axes.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))

        return np.min(zs)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
arrow_prop_dict = dict(mutation_scale=20, arrowstyle='-|>', color='k', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)
a = Arrow3D([0, 10], [0, 0], [0, 0], **arrow_prop_dict)
ax.add_artist(a)

plt.show()
```

Help came from [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21688).