# How can I connect two points in 3D scatter plot with arrow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to connect two points in a 3D scatter plot with an arrow. I tried using `quiver` with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xs1 = [40,50,34]
ys1 = [30,30,30]
zs1 = [98,46,63]

ax.scatter(xs1, ys1, zs1, s=100, c='g', marker='o')

ax.text(xs1[0], ys1[0], zs1[0], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[0]), str(ys1[0]), str(zs1[0])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')
ax.text(xs1[1], ys1[1], zs1[1], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[1]), str(ys1[1]), str(zs1[1])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')
ax.text(xs1[2], ys1[2], zs1[2], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[2]), str(ys1[2]), str(zs1[2])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')


ax.quiver(xs1[0], ys1[0], zs1[0], (xs1[0]-xs1[2]), (ys1[0]-ys1[2]), (zs1[0]-zs1[2]), length=30)


ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)

plt.show()
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Which looks something like this

[image]

The only way I was able to connect the two dots is by increasing the `length` of `quiver`, but if the `length` is more than what is required, it just passes through the other point.

Is there any better way to connect them without adjusting the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct own class based on `FancyArrow` to plot in 3d dimension:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xs1 = [40,50,34]
ys1 = [30,30,30]
zs1 = [98,46,63]

ax.scatter(xs1, ys1, zs1, s=100, c='g', marker='o')

ax.text(xs1[0], ys1[0], zs1[0], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[0]), str(ys1[0]), str(zs1[0])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')
ax.text(xs1[1], ys1[1], zs1[1], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[1]), str(ys1[1]), str(zs1[1])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')
ax.text(xs1[2], ys1[2], zs1[2], '(%s,%s,%s)' % (str(xs1[2]), str(ys1[2]), str(zs1[2])), size=30, zorder=5, color='k')

arw = Arrow3D([xs1[0],xs1[2]],[ys1[0],ys1[2]],[zs1[0],zs1[2]], arrowstyle="->", color="purple", lw = 3, mutation_scale=25)
ax.add_artist(arw)

ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize=30, labelpad=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Above code is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22867877/2666859) read it for more details.