# matplotlib.pyplot.quiver draws gigantic arrows, 'scale' or 'width' as parameter, gives "'Line3DCollection' object has no property 'units'" error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a graph with the path of a vector and the position of thissame vector at a given time. I am using quiver in 3D, but when I try to use `scale` or `width` in the parameters, it gives an error. It plots the vector, but it has a too-big arrow. The two "side lines", which are making arrow point are to big. How to make them a litle bit smaller?
[image: Output Graph]

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_autoscalex_on(True)
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, s=0.4 ) 
 #x, y and z are arrays with coordinates of points
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, x[10], y[10], z[10], color='red')
{}s'.format(step)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `nvec`? What are you expecting it to look like? If you want to plot a single arrow, have you considered `annotation` or `arrow` instead? Can you also add the code where you used `scale`. And have you tried `scale_units`? Setting `units`? Or [`length`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/quiver3d.html)?

Comment: 'nvec' is array of 3D vectors from which i plot only one (number 20). I would like this two side lines in arrow, to be shorter... units doesnt work... I dont know why

Comment: Please post example data for `nvec` the represent its actual shape and datatype. If it's a numpy array why index it as `[10][1]`? It should be `[10, 1]`

Comment: *"doesn't work"* means nothing. You need to post the code that you tried for combinations of all 4 parameters mentioned above, `scale`, `scale_units`, `units`, and `length`.

Comment: Also please remove the irrelevant lines of code like the comments, the `naslov=` and the `ax.set_title` and all the `ax.set_?label` lines

Comment: In short, one needs to see a [mcve] of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `arrow_length_ratio` rather than `scale`, since you are plotting in 3d rather than 2d.

This is from the [docs for 3d matplotlib objects](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html).

Try something like:

```
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, x[10], y[10], z[10], arrow_length_ratio=0.1, color='red')
```