# Arrow following 3D curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how to place an arrow following a path in a 3D plot

Here is an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.linspace(0,10,100)
x = np.sin(z)
y = np.cos(z)

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
```

I tried to do this with `FancyArrowPatch` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html. But the `path` argument only accepts a (x,y) argument.
How can this be transposed to 3D?

Comment: I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867620/putting-arrowheads-on-vectors-in-a-3d-plot

Comment: Hi, this makes an arrow. But it does not follow a path

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing off of @CT Zhu (from [Putting arrowheads on vectors in a 3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867620/putting-arrowheads-on-vectors-in-a-3d-plot) ; and @Ruli who fixed the `attribute error` in the newer versions of `matplotlib`), we can apply the `Arrow3D` logic on a `tuple` of `list`s of the last two values of `x`, `y`, and `z` so that the arrow head follows the curve of the path or line:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__((0, 0), (0, 0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def do_3d_projection(self, renderer=None):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, self.axes.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0], ys[0]), (xs[1], ys[1]))

        return np.min(zs)

z = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
x = np.sin(z)
y = np.cos(z)

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve', color='r')
arrow_prop_dict = dict(mutation_scale=20, arrowstyle='-|>', color='r', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)
arrow_head = (x[-2:], y[-2:], z[-2:])
a = Arrow3D(*arrow_head, **arrow_prop_dict)
ax.add_artist(a)

plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]

The credit should really go to @CT Zhu (and @Ruli) who basically did all of the work.