# Axes3D.text() Annotate 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, text, 3d

Can't get the 3D text working to annotate the scatter plot points.

Tried Axes3D.text, plt.text but keep getting 'missing required positional argument 's'. How do you annotate in 3D in a loop?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv (r'J:\Temp\Michael\Python\9785.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Scatter plot
for i in df.index:
    x = df.at[i,'x']
    y = df.at[i,'y']
    z = df.at[i,'h']
    ax.scatter(xs=x, ys=y, zs=z, s=20,color='red',marker='^')
    label = df.at[i,'to']
    Axes3D.text(x+0.8,y+0.8,z+0.8, label, zdir=x)
```

TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: Annotating a 3D scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)

Comment: [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/text3d.html) is the official documentation

Comment: @Sheldore thanks I've been checking those and trying to come right, but can't get it to work somehow...

Comment: Provide some initial lines of your dataframe so that we can run your code

Comment: problem was with the figure type - fig.gca() fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

to: ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

solved the problem. Used ax.text.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv (r'J:\Temp\Michael\Python\9785.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#Scatter plot
for i in df.index:
    df.set_index('to')
    x = df.at[i,'x']
    y = df.at[i,'y']
    z = df.at[i,'h']
    ax.scatter(xs=x, ys=y, zs=z, s=20,color='red',marker='^')
    ax.text(x+0.8,y+0.8,z+0.8, df.at[i,'to'], size=10, zorder=1)
```