# How to write values of coordinates on plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this function:

```
def draw(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, verName, GraphNum):
    plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6]);

    plt.xlim(0,3500);
    plt.ylim(0,100);

    if GraphNum == 1:
        plt.plot(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, 'r');
    if GraphNum == 2:
        plt.plot(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, 'g');  
    if GraphNum == 3:
        plt.plot(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, 'b');    

    plt.scatter(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, linewidths=1)
    plt.grid(axis)
    plt.xlabel('Ambient', color='r');
    plt.ylabel('Depth Grows', color='r'); # grayscale color
    plt.title(PngName, color='#afeeee');
    savefig(PngName+'.png');
```

I'm calling to this function 1,2 or 3 times.

according to the number of calls I draw graphs on the same plot (I'm doing the `plt.show()` after I finished all calls.) each graph in different color.
On each graph I mark the dots in a little circle with `plt.scatter(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, linewidths=1)`.

Now I want to write near each dot,  the values of x and y (LuxCoordinates, finalPix)
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [plt.annotate](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147430/190597) of its use.

See also [the Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) and [the Intro](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) for a review of the many options.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.
I saw this already but didn't understand how to actualize this in my code.