# Mapping Column Data to Graph Properties

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df that looks like this:

```
Qname    X    Y    Magnitude
Bob      5    19    10
Tom      6    20    20
Jim      3    30    30
```

I would like to make a visual text plot of the data. I want to plot the Qnames on a figure with their coordinates set =  X,Y and a s=Size.

I have tried:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
X = df.X
Y = df.Y
S = df.magnitude
Name = df.Qname
ax.text(X, Y, Name, size=S, color='red', rotation=0, alpha=1.0, ha='center', va='center')
fig.show()
```

However nothing is showing up on my plot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this the code you are running? Where does `ax` come from?

Comment: My apologies I am very new to this. I have edited my post and included all my code.

Comment: Why not just use the plot capabilities in the Pandas library?

Comment: Could you expand on that a little please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Matplotlib does not handle the text placement for you so you will probably need to play around with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# replace this with your existing code to read the dataframe
df = pd.read_clipboard()

plt.scatter(df.X, df.Y, s=df.Magnitude)


# annotate the plot
# unfortunately you have to iterate over your points
# see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5147112/553404

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5147112/553404
    # for better annotation options
    plt.annotate(row['Qname'], xy=(row['X'], row['Y']))

plt.show()
```