# mpld3 plot, annotations issues

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I'm using mpld3 to display graphs on an intranet website. I'm using the option of saving the graph to a dict and render it on the client side using mpld3.js.

The graph renders fine except when I want to use annotations. Those ones are clearly offset. And I don't understand why, because even if I set the offset to (0, 0), the annotations are still way off.

To illustrate this, I have copied and pasted the example given in this post:
[Matplotlib: How to put individual tags for a scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147430/2859089)

Here is the image as correctly generated by matplotlib:
[image: Matplotlib version]

Here is the one made with mpld3:
[image]

Note that both image are generated at the same time using the code in the link mentioned above.
The matplotlib one is made using:

```
plt.show()
```

and then manually saved.

The one from mpld3 is made using:

```
 graph_data = json.dumps(fig_to_dict(fig))
```

Then `graph_data` is generated on the client side using `mpld3.js`, which works perfectly fine except when using annotations.

Do you have any idea why it behaves like this?
Eventually I could just display the images generated directly from matplotlib, but the have interactive chart is a nice bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `plt.annotate` is a `mpl` feature that is not yet supported in `mpld3`.  I've added it to the [list of missing features](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/wiki#mpld3-missing-features).  Pull requests welcome!

For a hacky work-around, you can use `plt.text` to get the words and `plt.plot` to make any additional embellishments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345) # set seed for reproducibility

N = 10
data = np.random.random((N, 4))
labels = ['point{0}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
plt.scatter(
    data[:, 0], data[:, 1], marker = 'o', c = data[:, 2], s = data[:, 3]*1500,
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral'))
for label, x, y in zip(labels, data[:, 0], data[:, 1]):
    plt.text(x-.05, y+.05,
        label,
        ha = 'right', va = 'bottom')
    plt.plot([x-.05,x], [y+.05,y], 'k-')
```

Here is [a notebook that shows it in action](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/ccbbc7cd57948ac9926f).  You might also be interested in the [HTML Tooltips plugin](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/html_tooltips.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry the late reply. This does solve my problem. In the end I decided to directly display png images of the graphs instead of using mpld3 as I had other issues and have little budget allocated to develop what I've been asked to do.