# Label individual points in Sage plot

Tags: plot, scatter-plot, sage

This seems like a straightforward problem, yet I can't find a solution. In Sage, I've got about 30 sorted points for a `scatter_plot`, and I want to add the order position as a label. I know this is easy if I were working with a `graph` object, since I could use the `vertex_labels` option in `plot`. Is there a simple fix to get this to work for a `scatter_plot`, or would I need to do something like make the points vertices and keep track of the exact location of each point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you may have to use matplotlib directly or mess around with that method inside of Sage to get this.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point) for some related questions.

I've opened [Trac 20583](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/20583) for this.

Comment: That's about what I anticipated; thanks for the confirmation