# Adding text labels to a simple matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add text labels to a simple `matplotlib` chart and nothing I've tried has worked.

```
plt.plot(SpringLikes)
plt.xlabel("Event")
labels=("SpringThemes")
plt.ylabel("No. of Likes")
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's a simple plot of the # of FB Likes per Event.  I want the tick marks on the X axis to be the names of those events, which have been saved from a `pandas` Dataframe into the variable `SpringThemes`.

Any idea why this is not displaying the themes as the tickmark labels on the x axis?

Comment: FYI, simply defining a local variable 'labels' will not affect your plot. It is functionally the same for you to write `any_variable_name_here=("SpringThemes")`

Comment: I see.  So how could I take the text objects in my variable "SpringThemes" and use that to label the tick marks on the x axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: How to put individual tags for a scatter plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say for example you have a list for your x axis:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
```

You can add ticks on it like this:

```
plt.xticks([Game 1, Game 2, Game 3,Game 4])
```

Thus changing the x axis label.

Comment: I don't think that helps me.  I'm not looking to create a title for the chart, I'm looking to re-label the ticks on the x axis as the events themselves (i.e., "Game 1, Game 2, Game 3, etc..).  I have the names of the events stored in a variable called "SpringThemes," but I can't figure out how to replace the generic numbers on the x axis with the text in that variable.

Comment: You should have told that on your question also put up the whole code.

Comment: Check my answer.Hope it helps you :-)

Comment: Very helpful!  One more thing: I'd like to be able to generate those labels using my SpringThemes variable.  But when I add the line plt.xtics[(SpringThemes)] I get an error saying "tuple object not callable."  I know this is a dumb/newb question, but how can I get the plot to label the x ticks using the text in that SpringThemes variable?

Comment: That's not possible since you need to put ticks on each number,say you got 4 numbers then you need to add four ticks as you can see.

Comment: It sounds like I need to revise my entire plotting script.  I was just doing a simple plt.plot(SpringLikes) rather than identifying x and y variables.  When I added your code to mine, I still got the 'tuple object not callable' error

Comment: your x variable is something  like this right? : x = [2,4,6,8] .It's a good idea to store them in a list like that.

Comment: I'm using two variables, "SpringLikes" and "SpringThemes"  The SpringLikes is a list of the total number of likes per event.  The SpringThemes is a list of the NAMES of the events (which I would like to display as the tick marks).

Comment: @AndrewSmith have you tried `plt.xticks(SpringThemes)` i.e. without brackets

Comment: @Leo  Yes.  When I do, I get the following: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable