# plot emoji as pictures in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, emoji

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'❤': 10, '‍‍‍': 23, '': 13, '': 10, '': 13}
```

I want to plot the emojis as a bar, and draw them on the bar. At first I did like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43419590/7252805) (with `annotate`), but it looks bad, and it doesn't support some emojis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(range(1,6), a.values())
for label, x, y in zip(a.keys(), range(1,6), a.values()):
    plt.annotate(
        label, 
        xy=(x, y), xytext=(10,10),
        textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom',
        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.5', alpha=0),
        fontname='Segoe UI Emoji',
        fontsize=20)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```

As I said, looks bad:

[image]

I tried to ask [how to plot high quality emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47102873/7252805), but didn't get an answer.
How can I plot the emojis such that they will look good? I don't want to start web scraping the images and labeling them (because I'm pretty sure someone already did it). I'm using python 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is about not getting an answer, you may use [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). But make sure your question is well posed, i.e. contains in how far it is different from other questions on this topic, includes your system and relevant package versions etc.

Comment: I think the problem here lies in the font Matplotlib is using. Try changing the font using the RcParams in Matplotlib

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I decided to put a bounty on the previous question (that I edited now) considering the larger amount of views. I want to delete this question, but I can't because https://stackoverflow.com/q/47102873/7252805 is a duplicate of this one. Can you please open this question so I can delete this question?