# Error while using plt.text() in scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 batsman       balls    runs     strike_rate    6's     4's     Team    Highest_score
A Ashish Reddy  196     280     142.857143      16      15      DC      10
A Ashish Reddy  196     280     142.857143      16      15      SRH     36
A Chandila      7       4       57.142857       0       0       RR      4
A Chopra        75      53      70.666667       7       0       KKR     24...
```

What I am trying to do is plot a scatter plot so that I can compare 2 batsman. So I wrote a funtion:

```
batsman1='MS Dhoni'
batsman2='V Kohli'
def batsman_comparator():
    sns.FacetGrid(balls,hue='Team',size=8).map(mlt.scatter, "runs", "strike_rate", alpha=0.5).add_legend()
    bats1=balls[balls['batsman']==batsman1]
    bats2=balls[balls['batsman']==batsman2]
    mlt.scatter(bats1["runs"],bats1["strike_rate"],s=50,c='#55ff33')
    mlt.text(bats1["runs"],bats1["strike_rate"],batsman1,
        fontsize=10, weight='bold', color='#f46d43')
    mlt.scatter(bats2["runs"],bats2["strike_rate"],s=50,c='#f73545')
    mlt.text(bats2["runs"],bats2["strike_rate"], batsman2, 
        fontsize=10, weight='bold', color='#ff58fd')
    mlt.show()
batsman_comparator()
```

Okay so by using the function I was able to get the plots properly.
But as I added the **mlt.text()** inorder to show the names of the batsman on the particular points, I get a this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Now on removing the mlt.text() the function is working fine. How do I display the name for the batsman using the mlt.text(). Any other alternative is also fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be using `mlt.text()` correctly. See the Matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/api/text_api.html?highlight=text#module-matplotlib.text). I believe the `text()` function can only be applied at a single point. I think you might instead be looking for `mlt.annotate()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147430/5548599) StackOverflow question might be helpful.